# when I click submit button multiple times(when it's loading to make a post), the post is made multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm using django and when I was finishing up my project I realized this was happening...(I should've done testing I guess) I'm not sure how to fix this problem. I googled around,some people using jquery but I don't quite get how that's helping. 
this is my code in views.py

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):

     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

     def form_valid(self, form):

            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # any manual settings go here

            #self.object.category = Category.objects.filter(category__in=categories).all()

            self.object.moderator = self.request.user
            self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 

            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))

     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

this is my form

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

#   category = CategoryChoices()

    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="plz enter")

    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200,
                         help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.", required=False)
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        widgets = {
            'category':Select2Widget,
        }
        exclude = ['pub_date', 'moderator', 'rank_score','slug', 'image']
```

this is my html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/add_post/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
<!--{% for tag in person.tags.all %}{{ tag.word }} {% endfor %}-->

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Post">
    </form>
    <div>
</div>
```

when I click submit button here to make a post, it loads and when it's loading I tried clicking submit button again then when it finished loading up two same posts are made. How do I fix this? Thank you

Comment: *"I should've done testing I guess"* - Yeah, maybe. You could use javascript to disable the submit button after it's pressed the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(self.object.get_absolute_url))
```

Define the get_absolute_url in the model, it should refer to a view details and not to a form.

Comment: isn't this irrelevant to the question I asked....it won't make any difference where I put that

Comment: `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post'` seems like a redirection to the same url, because of the word "post". You should check your urls.py though

Comment: redirecting to the post method, which it does. the question I'm asking is when I click submit button twice before page loads then two posts are made.

Comment: OK, but why are you redirecting to a post once the form is saved and done? maybe if you will redirect to GET it will solve the issue

Comment: maybe I didn't put my words right in this question, I created the one that's more clear I think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331574/prevent-multiple-submissions-when-user-clicks-submit-button-multiple-times-befor/35331786?noredirect=1#comment58371594_35331786