# prevent multiple submissions when user clicks submit button multiple times before loading to the new page

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have googled around and it seems like there are many possibilities for php. But I haven't found anything good solution for django. I saw some people using client side javascript code for this, but I just don't get how to fix this. Problem I;m having is:when user writes a post, and click submit button fast twice before new page gets loaded then two posts will be made. Here's my code, thanks in advance.
my html

```
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/add_post/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

my views.py

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):

    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        # any manual settings go here

        #self.object.category = Category.objects.filter(category__in=categories).all()

        self.object.moderator = self.request.user
        self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 
        self.object.thumbnail = extractt(self.object.content)
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Edit: I changed it to like this

```
{% block content %}
<div class="col-sm-5">
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/add_post/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
<input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="올리기">
</form>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="width:400px; height:250px; border:1px solid black;">
<h3>rule</h3>

</div>

<div class="col-sm-3" style="width:420px; height:750px; border:1px solid black;" >
<h3>ad</h3>
</div>
    {% endblock %}
<script>
    jQuery('input[name=submit]').on('click', function(){
 if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
   return false;
 }
 else{
  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
 }
});
    </script>
   {% include 'footer.html' %}
```

Final Edit: hope this is right? any suggestion?

```
import datetime

class PostCreateView(CreateView):

    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        # any manual settings go here

        #self.object.category = Category.objects.filter(category__in=categories).all()

        self.object.moderator = self.request.user
        self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 
        self.object.thumbnail = extractt(self.object.content)
        self.object.save()

        if not hasattr(self.request.session['last_submitted']):
            self.request.session['last_submitted'] = datetime.datetime.now()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))
        else:
            delta = datetime.datetime.now() - self.request.session['last_submitted']
            if delta.seconds < 60: # assume allow re-submit after 60 seconds
                return http.HttpForbidden() #or some other better message??
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Edit with the solution provided

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):

     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

     def form_valid(self,form):

        if not hasattr(self.request.session['last_submitted']):
            last_submitted = pickle.dumps(datetime.datetime.now())
            self.request.session['last_submitted'] = last_submitted
            save_it = True
        else:
            last_submitted = pickle.loads(self.request.session['last_submitted'])
            delta = datetime.datetime.now() - last_submitted
            save_it = (delta.seconds > 60) # assume allow re-submit after 60 seconds

        if save_it:
          self.object = form.save(commit=False)
          # any manual settings go here

          #self.object.category =      Category.objects.filter(category__in=categories).all()

          self.object.moderator = self.request.user
          self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 
          self.object.thumbnail = extractt(self.object.content)
          self.object.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))
        else:
           # consider redirect as usual, if the user just clicked twice by mistake
           return self.form_invalid(form) # or Http error code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the buttton:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="preventDouble">
```

With jQuery:

```
$("#preventDouble").on("submit",function(){
    $(this).unbind("submit");
    $(this).on("submit",function(){return false;});
};
```

After the first submit, jQuery will attach an event that will cancel further submits.

Note that this event does not check if the form was actually successfully submited to the server.

This may answer your question, but it's a safer and better approach to track multiple submits on the server, e.g. adding a "last_submitted" attribute to the session, and prevent further submits if datetime.datetime.now is less than 1 minute from session.last_submitted:

```
import datetime
import pickle

def form_valid(self,form):

    if not hasattr(self.request.session['last_submitted']):
        last_submitted = pickle.dumps(datetime.datetime.now())
        self.request.session['last_submitted'] = last_submitted
        save_it = True
    else:
        last_submitted = pickle.loads(self.request.session['last_submitted'])
        delta = datetime.datetime.now() - last_submitted
        save_it = (delta.seconds > 60): # assume allow re-submit after 60 seconds

    if save_it:
      self.object = form.save(commit=False)
      # any manual settings go here

      #self.object.category =      Category.objects.filter(category__in=categories).all()

      self.object.moderator = self.request.user
      self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 
      self.object.thumbnail = extractt(self.object.content)
      self.object.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))
    else:
       # consider redirect as usual, if the user just clicked twice by mistake
       return self.form_invalid(form) # or Http error code
```

Edit

```
import datetime
import pickle

class PostCreateView(CreateView):

     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

     def form_valid(self,form):

        if not hasattr(self.request.session['last_submitted']):
            last_submitted = pickle.dumps(datetime.datetime.now())
            self.request.session['last_submitted'] = last_submitted
            save_it = True
        else:
            last_submitted = pickle.loads(self.request.session['last_submitted'])
            delta = datetime.datetime.now() - last_submitted
            save_it = (delta.seconds > 60) # assume allow re-submit after 60 seconds

        if save_it:
          self.object = form.save(commit=False)
          # any manual settings go here

          #self.object.category =      Category.objects.filter(category__in=categories).all()

          self.object.moderator = self.request.user
          self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 
          self.object.thumbnail = extractt(self.object.content)
          self.object.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))
        else:
           # consider redirect as usual, if the user just clicked twice by mistake
           return self.form_invalid(form) # or Http error code
```

Comment: hmmm I agree with you, that probably is the best approach out there. Restricting user trying to post more than one in one minute....do you know how to do that? by the way thanks for that idea :)

Comment: hmm, sorry I'm a noobie..(its my first project). just to make sure that code goes into my views.py where class PostCreateView(CreateView) is??

Comment: Yes. continue is usually form.save(), refuse is some message you want to send to the user

Comment: hi umm, my final approach is the one I edited up there, do you mind taking a look at this?

Comment: updated the answer. Note that you may want to Httpredirect without error after second submit, if the user submitted twice by error, so you just ignore it and redirect as usual

Comment: this gives me KeyError at /add_post/
'last_submitted'
when I just post one with one click

Comment: This gives me same error, KeyError at /add_post/
'last_submitted'...I will post what I did

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your project is using jquery lib or not. if it does try following:

```
jQuery('input[name=submit]').on('click', function(){
 if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
   return false;
 }
 else{
  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
 }
});
```

What this will do is check if button is already clicked or not. If it does it won't resubmit the page.
If you are not using any client side library then i can change it to Native js.

Comment: hello, thank you. Yes I use jquery in my project. But I'm not very familiar with js and jquery. I will try that right now, thanks

Comment: So, I tried putting your code in my html file, between<script> </script>. But this won't work...did I do it wrong?

Comment: once your page is loaded try running it in browser console. Then try clicking the button. It will give you an idea if it works. It probably will require dom ready function. Try in console once.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.....I dont get any error or it's doing the one I want

Comment: after running the code you still see multiple post requests?

Comment: yes, I'll post what I changed...please take a peak at this